# Nodejs how to get current day without timezone

Tags: node.js, date

So I have a code in nodejs where I am getting a current date and time.

```
var timestamp = new Date().toString();
```

My output looks like this:

```
Wed Nov 09 2016 16:02:32 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

Can anybody please give me an advice how to get rid of `GMT+0100 (CET)` in my output?

Comment: Do you still want the time to be in CET, just without the 'GMT+0100 (CET)' bit at the end, or do you want the current date in UTC?

Comment: You want to get the date-time instance without information about the timezone, or a textual representation of said date-time instance without the timezone?

Comment: Just a textual representation should not be with timezone, otherwise everything is right. I just want to "hide" `GMT+0100 (CET)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the UTC date/time then use `toUTCString()`:

```
new Date().toUTCString();
// 'Wed, 09 Nov 2016 15:11:53 GMT'
```

If you want a standard UTC ISO8601 timestamp use `toISOString()`:

```
new Date().toISOString()
// '2016-11-09T15:13:00.380Z'
```

If you literally just want to get rid of `GMT+0100 (CET)` then:

```
new Date().toString().replace(' GMT+0100 (CET)', '');
// 'Wed Nov 09 2016 15:15:05'
```

or:

```
var now = new Date()
now.toString().substr(0, now.toString().indexOf(' GMT'))
// 'Wed Nov 09 2016 15:15:05'
```

Which will work for all timezones.

Comment: Awesome! thank you the last option was that one I have been looking for. Cheers!

Comment: No problem! If that's what you were after then I've updated my answer with a solution than should work for all timezones.

Comment: One more little question. How do I now order timestamps so I see the most recent? `ORDER BY datetime(timestamp)` seems to not work for me :/

Comment: Are you saving them into a database and wanting to do this in SQL? Or is this still in node.js?

Comment: They are saved into SQLite database and then I render them in node.js to the index file like this `db.each("SELECT * FROM scene WHERE user_id = ? ORDER BY datetime(timestamp) DESC", req.user.id, function(err, row) { //...`

Comment: From the [SQLite docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) it looks like it could be an issue with the date formatting, but it's probably better to create a new question for that. If you're saving that timestamp to a DB then the ISO8601 timestamp might be better. If you're displaying the date to a user then you can convert ISO8601 to the local timezone in the client, this way you don't have to worry about time zones, day light saving, etc. Just a suggestion :)

Comment: Thanks once again :)